# Designing issue in JQuery mobile with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows-xp, ios-simulator, jquery-mobile

I am creating mobile application in asp.net webform targeting IPhone, Android and blackberry. I am using JQuery-Mobile for the same.
Below is my first page I have developed with jquery-mobile.

[image: JQuery-mobile page]

I don't have iphone, android and blackberry. So my questions are:

1. Best Simulator I can use on windows XP/ Windows Server 2008 for Iphone, Andriod and Blackberry
2. Also, when I am running the application on the browser it is looking wierd. I mean textbox size, buttons. Is this the way it looks on normal webpage or it's my faulty design?
3. As I am developing application in asp.net, do I need to install latest browser which support HTML5 and CSS3 because below browser is IE7.

Comment: "Below is my first page I have developed with jquery-mobile" nope, not there. Could you try add it again please?

Comment: @Bernhard Hofmann I have edited the question. I was too quick that I forget to add image. Now it is added, please check it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Emulator for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html)

[Simulators for Blackberry](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp)

I'm sure Apple has one too - but I think you need to register as a iOS developer before you can get your hands on it.  I believe using third-party iOS emulators is against Apple's policy.

Comment: Thanks! Does my web app look fine in the browser?

Comment: It has no gradients and no rounded corners. the size is a normal thing. You can fiddle with `label` tags and field containers and better button setup to make the layout better.

Answer (score 1):

**An old IE is not the best choice to test the capabilities of a HTML5+javascript framework...**

For daily basis it's quite ok to use `Firefox` or any `WebKit` based browser (`chrome`, `safari` ...)

Emulators are very helpful, but to be sure your product works well you will probably need to give it a try on an actual device. I have already seen some reports of problems that show up only when working with the real device.

A team that I do some JQM stuff for has bought a cheap old ipod touch for testing. It's the most demanding apple product you can get. It has the oldest browser, causes most problems and is the slowest. Best choice! :)